# What's the best way to see logged in users in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, user-management, users, user-accounts, user-profile

Right now I use a powershell script to see the currently logged in users. But I don't see if their session is idle, active or inactive. I can see when the session was started, that's it.
Is there an easy way to see how many users are currently logged in to the server I am logged in and see their status? It should not be remotely executed. 
I would like to avoid third party tools if possible.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use the `query user` command

**Query User Command**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490801.aspx

Comment: Does anyone know what API calls provide this information?

Comment: @NetMage I was just looking for that API myself. Not sure, but maybe check [**NetWkstaUserEnum**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: It looks like the [**LsaEnumerateLogonSessions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378275(v=vs.85).aspx) function is better as described on [CodeProject - Enumerating Logon Sessions](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7483/Enumerating-Logon-Sessions) (there is ancient source code to download).

Answer (score 53):

Open the Task-Manager and see the users tab. There you will find a list of users and their status.

[image: Task-Manager]

Comment: thanks, but this status is not "correct" it's empty while the cmd  query user shows me "active"

Answer (score 5):

"quser" command will give you the active now users

the same result will give you the "qwinsta" command

Answer (score 4):

```
Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName 192.168.1.9 | Select-Object UserName
```

where `192.168.1.9` is the IP of the server

Comment: This only seems to return 1 user for me.

Comment: Worth noting that this will only return console logins, and not RDP sessions.

Answer (score 3):

Use **quser** or **query user** to check users connected

```
quser

query user
```

[image: quser or query user]

Use **qwinsta** or query **session** to check sessions connected

```
qwinsta

query session
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use the "UserLock" application to see which users logged in. By this 3rd party tool you can manage the session of the users as well as remote desktop sessions. It is a great tool in this case. I suggest you try this tool.

Answer (score 1):

Its easy in Server 2016 when you are in a session:

Click the search glass bottom left on task bar

Type *gateway* in the box and this should bring up "Remote Desktop Gateway Manager"; select it.

Click on the ">" next to the RDS server you want to view (RDS-01) for most I guess,
then select the *monitoring* folder

You can now see who is logged on, how long for, since what time and can disconnect them or set connection limits.

Please note you probably need certain admin rights to do this, but it works for me.